# Adding to hash table in C++?

Tags: c++, hash

Guessing I'm doing something stupidly simple wrong, but can't seem to find an answer in existing stack overflow questions. I'm trying to implement a simple hash table containing lists of strings in C++ for a programming class. My add() function appears to be working correctly from inside the function, but as soon as I check the hash table's contents from the contains() function it's obvious that something's gone wrong.

```
void string_set::add(const char *s) { 

//copy s into new char array str
char str[strlen(s)];
strcpy(str, s);
//find hash value of string
int hValue = string_set::hash_function(s);

//create new node to contain string
node* newNode = new node();
newNode->s = str;

//if string's position in hash table is empty, add directly and 
//set newNode's next to null. if not, set newNode next to 
//current first node in list and then add to hash table
if(hash_table[hValue] == NULL) {
    hash_table[hValue] = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
} else {
    newNode->next = hash_table[hValue];
    hash_table[hValue] = newNode;
}
cout << "string added: " << hash_table[hValue]->s << endl;

return;
}
```

This prints the expected string; i.e. if I add "e" it prints "e".
But when I call this immediately after:

```
int string_set::contains(const char *s) {
//find hash value of string
int hValue = string_set::hash_function(s);

//return inital value of hash table at that value
cout << "hash table points to " << hash_table[hValue]->s << endl;
}
```

It prints some junk. What have I done?

Since this is for a class, the specifications have been provided and I have no opportunity to change the way the hash table is set up. I'll be adding exceptions etc later, just want to get the add function working. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, new to stack overflow and not sure about comment formatting! Yes, I can use std::string. The hash function is as follows

```
int string_set::hash_function(const char *s) {
int cValue =0;
int stringSum = 0; 
unsigned int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    cValue = (int) s[i];
    stringSum = stringSum + cValue;
}
stringSum = stringSum % HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
return stringSum;
}
```

Comment: Likely a Hash issue, what are you using for your hash function and what is the declaration of your hash table object? Best would be to simple use the standard library's hash function for strings http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash and hopefully you wouldn't do something like use an array as the hash table ;)

Comment: `str` is a local variable and ceases to exist as soon as the function ends, a quick fix would be to use `char* str = new char[strlen(s) + 1];` (which will need to be `delete`d eventually), but raw memory allocations will also set you up for surprises down the line. Does the assignment allow you to use a `std::string`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice but to use an array as the hash table, that's part of the assignment. :-(

Comment: The hash function puts you at risk for overflow. But yes, the issue is that the char pointer is falling out of scope as mentioned above.

Comment: Using an array for the hash table buckets is a separate issue from using a char array as the text storage, but perhaps you'd not allowed to do the latter either....

Comment: Thank you, Aiden and user657267, you folks helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use local variable outside of its function scope. This is an undefined behavior in C++. In your compiler realization, stack frame is invalidated, so all `newNode->s` pointers became dangling, memory, they are pointing, is already used to store different stack frame. To solve this issue you could either dynamically allocate memory on the heap or use `std::string` instead of `char*` which is the best approach.

Also its worth pointing out, that standard C++ library already have hash table realization `std::unordered_map`.